# Can I hook into pytest assertion failures?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I spend a good part of my day squinting at failed `pytest` output to see why two objects, or two collections of objects, don't quite match.

```
def test_flidgets_are_equal(expected_flidgets):
   assert Flidgitator(44) == expected_flidget
```

The default printed output from `pytest`, even with the `-vv` option, is a big mess. Nothing aligns correctly and with any sort of complicated object (let alone a list of objects) it's very difficult to see where the mismatches are, or even if two collections have the same cardinality.

OK, so I wrote a cool thing to pretty-print diffs between objects and (sorted) lists of objects. I can debug a failed test and use it like this:

```
$ pytest test_flidgitator.py --pdb

(test fails)
>>> from my_cool_util import diff; diff(Flidgitator(44), expected_flidgets)

[0] ✓ [Flidget] EQUAL

· capacitance   98.6
· chromaticity  19.5
· id            FLIDGET_ONE


[1] ✘ [Flidget] NOT EQUAL

· capacitance   98.6
· id            FLIDGET_TWO

+ chromaticity  23.8
- chromaticity  46.1


2 total / 1 equal / 1 not equal
```

I can use a keyboard macro (TextExpander, etc.) to automate the `import` bit, but I still have to manually type in the two objects/lists I want to compare on every failure. Is there some way I can avoid the typing and hook into the two sides of a failed `pytest` assertion to automatically call my utility on a failed test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's a hook [pytest_assertrepr_compare](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/assert.html#defining-your-own-explanation-for-failed-assertions), where you can customize the output of unfullfiled `assert`

Comment: Perfect! That's what I was looking for.

Comment: Above link is dead, but docs are [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/assert.html#defining-your-own-explanation-for-failed-assertions).